# How to set multiple "order by"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm about to make a subscriptions list to my website, but I can't find a solution for multiple "order by" in my query, that actually works.

My current code is:

```
 select name from data_subscriptions 
 where authVal="1" 
 order by id desc, name asc limit 100
```

But I only order by id desc, and not the name asc.

Database:

```
[1] ( id=1, authVal=1, name=Alex )
[2] ( id=2, authVal=1, name=Jens )
```

It shows Jens, and then Alex - What do I do wrong?

Comment: This behavior is by design.  Your question doesn't actually make sense.  What do you think "sorting by two properties" means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think maybe what you wanted was this:

```
order by name asc, id desc
```

This amounts to *order by the name but if the names are the same, then order by id*

Your existing code would order by id, and if the ids are the same, then order by the name.  My guess is that the ids are never the same, so it always just ends up in id order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by most significant to least significant.

```
order by lastname asc, firstname asc
```

This will order by last name then first name. The first name is only considered when last name matches between two rows.

```
Doe, John
Smith, Able
Smith, Joe
Smith, John
```

In your case the id is most likely your PK. In that case it should never match anyone else's so the secondary ordering never comes into play.